# can not understand the logic of these code (AJAX & JSON)

Tags: json, ajax, image, logic, refresh

I am a student who studying software Engineering. For this semester I am studying basic wed-application. I will have to face my final exam on 17/5/2023 however, my lecturer ask us to focus on AJAX and JSON BUT ALL she has done is just sending these code to us and ask us study without any explanation on the code. **Therefore I don't Understand it AT All (the logic).Hence may Someone please explain the code to me. The part I don't understand is the code after the images variable.** My lecturer was useless she always end the class within 30 minutes although it is a 3 hours class. And she did not reply any of my message/email. And I had also tried to find some online resource, but I still could not get it. Hence I have no choice for it. Anyways, **Sorry for spending your time on this** and complain on my lecturer. **Appreciate for your help. Thanks.**

Here the code:

```
var images = {
    'set 1' : [
    'pic1.jpg',
    'pic2.jpg',
    'pic3.jpg',
    'pic4.jpg',
    'pic5.jpg',
    'pic6.jpg',
    'pic7.jpg',
    'pic8.jpg',
    'pic9.jpg',
    'pic10.jpg'
    ],
    'set 2' : [
    'pic2.jpg',
    'pic3.jpg',
    'pic4.jpg',
    'pic5.jpg',
    'pic6.jpg',
    'pic7.jpg',
    'pic8.jpg',
    'pic9.jpg',
    'pic10.jpg',
    'pic11.jpg',
    'pic12.jpg',
    'pic5.jpg',
    'pic6.jpg',
    'pic7.jpg',
    'pic8.jpg'
    ],
    'set 3' : [
    'pic1.jpg',
    'pic2.jpg',
    'pic3.jpg',
    'pic4.jpg',
    'pic5.jpg',
    'pic6.jpg',
    'pic7.jpg',
    'pic8.jpg',
    'pic9.jpg',
    'pic10.jpg',
    'pic11.jpg',
    'pic12.jpg',
    'pic4.jpg',
    'pic5.jpg',
    'pic6.jpg'
    ]
   };
   $(document).ready(function(){ // on document ready
    $('#gallery').gallery();
   });
   $.fn.gallery = function() {
    var self = this;
    var setimgs;
    this.each(function() {
    var g = this;

    g.load_sets = function(el) { // function - load sets of images
    $.each(images, function(key, value) {
    $(el).append('<li><a id="'+key+'" href="#" title="'+key+'">'+key+'</a></li>');
    });

    var sets = $(el).find('li a');
    $(sets).click(function() { // binding onclick to our sets
    var set = $(this).attr('id');
    g.setimgs = images[set];
    $(g).find('#thumbs').html('');
    g.load_thumbs($(g).find('#thumbs')[0], 0);
    $(g).find('#loading').html('Loading <strong>1</strong> of '+g.setimgs.length+'images');
    });
    sets[0].click();
    }

    g.load_thumbs = function(el, index) { // function - load thumbs of set
    $(el).append('<li><img id="' + g.setimgs[index] + '" src="images/thumb_' +
   g.setimgs[index] + '" /></li>');
    var tn = new Image();
    $(tn).load(function() {
    var a = $($(el).find('li')[index]).find('img')[0];
    $(a).append(this);

    $(a).click(function() { // binding onclick to thumbs
    var i = $(this).attr('id');
   $(g).find('#photo').attr('src', 'images/'+i);
   return false;
    });
    if ((index + 1) < g.setimgs.length) {
    g.load_thumbs(el, (index + 1));
   $(g).find('#loading strong').html(index + 2);
    } else {
    $(g).find('#loading').html('Finished loading <strong>' + g.setimgs.length +
   '</strong> images');
    $($(g).find('#thumbs li img')[0]).click();
    }
    });
    tn.src = 'images/thumb_' + g.setimgs[index];
    }
    
    // oninit - load sets for gallery
    g.load_sets($(g).find('#sets')[0]);
    });
   };
```

for example I don't know what is **g, fn, el** stand for.
I had tried out the code it work, but I don't understand it (the logic) at all. **Sorry again** for spending your time. ‍♂️‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps. I put comments into the code to help explain what it is doing. This really has nothing to do with AJAX though. It is pretty much a lot of JQuery. Here is a reference so you can learn more about it. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_jquery_selectors.asp

```
//This is just your test json

var images = {
    'set 1': [
        'pic1.jpg',
        'pic2.jpg',
        'pic3.jpg',
        'pic4.jpg',
        'pic5.jpg',
        'pic6.jpg',
        'pic7.jpg',
        'pic8.jpg',
        'pic9.jpg',
        'pic10.jpg'
    ],
    'set 2': [
        'pic2.jpg',
        'pic3.jpg',
        'pic4.jpg',
        'pic5.jpg',
        'pic6.jpg',
        'pic7.jpg',
        'pic8.jpg',
        'pic9.jpg',
        'pic10.jpg',
        'pic11.jpg',
        'pic12.jpg',
        'pic5.jpg',
        'pic6.jpg',
        'pic7.jpg',
        'pic8.jpg'
    ],
    'set 3': [
        'pic1.jpg',
        'pic2.jpg',
        'pic3.jpg',
        'pic4.jpg',
        'pic5.jpg',
        'pic6.jpg',
        'pic7.jpg',
        'pic8.jpg',
        'pic9.jpg',
        'pic10.jpg',
        'pic11.jpg',
        'pic12.jpg',
        'pic4.jpg',
        'pic5.jpg',
        'pic6.jpg'
    ]
};

// This is telling you that when the "document.ready" event triggers on your document then do this
$(document).ready(function () { // on document ready

    // This is selecting the gallery element(s) (id="gallery") in your document and calling the gallery() function
    $('#gallery').gallery();
});

// everything below this is what happens when you call .gallery()
$.fn.gallery = function () {
    // never used
    var self = this;
    // never used
    var setimgs;

    // loop through the gallery elements
    this.each(function () {
        // g = this particular element
        var g = this;
        // This is what happens when you call g.load_sets(). el is what you pass into the function
        g.load_sets = function (el) { // function - load sets of images
            // Go through the images variable passing in each key ("set 1", "set 2", "set 3") and value from the JSON (the array associated with the key)
            $.each(images, function (key, value) {
                // Adds a list item to the element
                $(el).append('<li><a id="' + key + '" href="#" title="' + key + '">' + key + '</a></li>');
            });
            // This will find every list item that has a link in the list of sets we just made
            var sets = $(el).find('li a');
            // Binding an event handler for the click event for each of the elements
            $(sets).click(function () { // binding onclick to our sets
                // makes set equal to the id of the list item
                var set = $(this).attr('id');
                // this will set the array of images related to the set
                g.setimgs = images[set];
                // finds the element in this element with the id="thumbs" and sets the html to blank
                $(g).find('#thumbs').html('');
                // this will take the first element of the element with the id="thumbs"
                g.load_thumbs($(g).find('#thumbs')[0], 0);
                // this finds the element with id="loading" and sets it's html
                $(g).find('#loading').html('Loading <strong>1</strong> of ' + g.setimgs.length + 'images');
            });
            // this simulates a click event
            sets[0].click();
        }
        // what happens when you call g.load_thumbs(). el being the element passed into the function and index is also passed in
        g.load_thumbs = function (el, index) { // function - load thumbs of set
            // Append a list item with an image
            $(el).append('<li><img id="' + g.setimgs[index] + '" src="images/thumb_' +
                g.setimgs[index] + '" /></li>');
            // load the image
            var tn = new Image();
            $(tn).load(function () {
                // find your current list item and append the image
                var a = $($(el).find('li')[index]).find('img')[0];
                $(a).append(this);
                // bind the onclick so when you click the thumbnail it will open a full size image
                $(a).click(function () { // binding onclick to thumbs
                    var i = $(this).attr('id');
                    $(g).find('#photo').attr('src', 'images/' + i);
                    return false;
                });
                // Keep doing this until you make it all the way through the associated images
                if ((index + 1) < g.setimgs.length) {
                    g.load_thumbs(el, (index + 1));
                    $(g).find('#loading strong').html(index + 2);
                } else {
                    // when finished change the id="loading" text
                    $(g).find('#loading').html('Finished loading <strong>' + g.setimgs.length +
                        '</strong> images');
                    // simulate click on the first thumbnail
                    $($(g).find('#thumbs li img')[0]).click();
                }
            });
            // set the image source
            tn.src = 'images/thumb_' + g.setimgs[index];
        }

        // oninit - load sets for gallery
        g.load_sets($(g).find('#sets')[0]);
    });
};
```